How to get the size of the Angular Material button? (AM version >7.2)
When using Angular Material (version > 7.2.2): The Angular Material team removed the (previously available) globally accessible CSS custom property "--mdc-icon-button-state-layer-size".
AFAIK, it's now not possible anymore to know the size of a button in Angular Material. Is there any other way to know the size of a Material button? (I feel a bit ashamed to use Angular Material, now that I have to ask such questions).
I asked this question already on GitHub (https://github.com/angular/components/issues/28738); but all I got was a off-topic answer by an Google employee and the issue was closed and it seems to have been erased, behind the sofa and gone into the Google void.
I was expecting to get the size of an Angular Material Button.

You can use getBoundingClientRect to get the size of the button.

Add a template variable to the button you want to get the size of.
Use viewChild or @ViewChild to get the button.

Make sure to add the { read: ElementRef } option.


use getBoundingClientRect() on the nativeElement to get the size.

Based on your Github question, here is a working example.
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [MatButtonModule],
  template: `
    <button #btn mat-flat-button color="primary">My Button</button>
  `,
})
export class App {
  btn = viewChild('btn', { read: ElementRef });

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    const rect = this.btn()?.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect();
    console.log(rect);
    // Output:
    // { x: 0, y: 0, width: 106, height: 36, top: 0, left: 0 }
  }
}

Here is the StackBlitz code, it calculates half the button size and sets a CSS variable called --half-height that can be used on other items in the CSS using var(--half-height).


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [MatButtonModule],
  styles: `
    :host {
      .wrapper {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        gap: 20px;
      }

      button {
        flex: 1;
      }

      .box {
        flex: 1;
        height: var(--half-height);
        background: red;
      }
    }
  `,
  template: `
  <div class="wrapper">
    <button #btn mat-flat-button color="primary">My Button</button>

    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  btn = viewChild('btn', { read: ElementRef });

  set halfBinding(value: string) {
    document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--half-height', value);
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    const rect = this.btn()?.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect();
    this.halfBinding = rect.height / 2 + 'px';
  }
}




Could we set a globally available CSS custom property with this? E.g. in Angular's styles.css under ":root"?
In you example you are setting the CSS custom property under the ":host" of the app component.

yeah you should be able to.

I just tried it. It does not work in my scenario because it does not affect the CSS custom properties in dialogs. I looked at the DOM: the dialogs are sibling DOM elements of the app component's element :-( Different scopes.
It works when being used in any component that is a descendant of the app component though. So for anyone not using dialogs this is crazy (I mean... really) but working workaround until Angular material exposes that custom property again (if ever).

It is set on the document element

Ah, sorry, you already adjusted the example so that the property is set on the document element before my last comments. I'll delete my comments, now that these don't make sense anymore.
Yes, it works now.
Thanks you very much again, this made my day!
